# CoreData entity's are not being correctly initialised

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord

im having a hard time with what it seems a very simple task. Im trying to create an entity (LVUser) and calling a custom method implemented in the class previously mentioned. Every attempt i made returns me an unrecognised selector sent to instance error. Im using MagicalRecord in my project but also tried with CoreData raw methods without luck anyway.

First Attempt

```
LVUser* user = [LVUser MR_createEntity];
[user signInWithDelegete:self];
```

Second Attempt

```
LVUser* user = [LVUser MR_createInContext:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
[user signInWithDelegete:self];
```

Third Attempt

```
LVUser* user = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity: [LVUser MR_entityDescription]          insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
[user signInWithDelegete:self];
```

The last example gives me this warning

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'LVUser *' with an expression of type 'NSManagedObject *'
```

I don't get what i'm doing wrong, they are compatible pointer types indeed.

I tried deleting Xcode Derived Data and clean & build.

Comment: Does your model specify the custom class name?

Comment: Thanks!! I thought the name of the entity had to be the same as the custom class! This fixed it!